# Como fazer ranking com PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Bom, eu tenho um problema, sei como puxar o ranking e tudo.

Minha dúvida é que eu vou puxar os 6 com mais pontuação, e queria que os 3 primeiros tivesse um fundo diferente, tipo:

O que estiver em primeiro lugar: amarelo;

O de segundo lugar: azul;

O de terceiro lugar: vermelho;

O resto: cinza;

**Como posso fazer isso?**

Código:

```
<?php
$rank = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum ORDER BY pontos DESC LIMIT 6") or die(mysql_error()); ?> 
 <?php $i = 0; while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rank)){ $i++; ?>
<div style="background: gray;width: 60px;height: 20px;padding: 20px;">
<?php echo $row['username']; ?> com <?php echo $row['pontos']; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Seria um ranking do que extamente, @Kloves?

Comment: Usuários com mais posts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Elabore da seguinte forma:

```
<?
    #Pontuação
    function coresPts($posicao){

        switch($posicao){

            case 0: 
                $cor = "#FFCC00";
                break;

            case 1:
                $cor = "#000000";
                break;

            case 2:
                $cor = "#CCCCCCC";
                break;

        }

        return $cor;

    }

# Buscando pontuação
$rank = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forum ORDER BY pontos DESC LIMIT 0, 6") or die(mysql_error());

    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rank)){
        $i++; 
?>
<div style="background: <? echo coresPts($i); ?>;width: 60px;height: 20px;padding: 20px;">
    <?php echo $row['username']; ?> com <?php echo $row['pontos']; ?>
</div>
<? } ?>
```

Explicação: Criamos uma função chamada `coresPts` que buscará a pontuação de acordo com o `increment` do `$i`. E então retornamos a cor correta para cada uma das posições, basta você alterar a `$cor` de cada posição. A posição `0` seria a primeira posição, `1` a segunda posição e `2` a terceira posição.

Comment: Alterei, estava incorreto o switch(), a variável dele coloquei outra, desculpe. Agora está certa.

Comment: Deu certo @kloves?

Comment: Deu sim, obrigado.